# fit a GARCH model to time series from log returns - error- 'Attribut 'names' [3604] must have same length as vector [3603]'

Tags: r, vector, time-series, quantmod

trying to fit a GARCH (1,1) model from a time series I get the error message:

Attribut 'names' [3604] must have the same length as vector [3603]

the vector of log returns looks like

```
> head(ret.log)
                SPY
2000-01-03           NA
2000-01-04 -0.039845909
2000-01-05  0.001773961
2000-01-06 -0.016269696
2000-01-07  0.056494498
2000-01-10  0.003399234
```

and has length

```
> length(ret.log)
[1] 3604
```

so there seems to be a dimension problem that only is caused by a difference in the length of two inputs.

Maybe I have to skip one row of the ret.log vector because the names are not part of the regression?

Comment: It is most likely caused by the first `NA`. Remove it and check if problem disappears.